# Perdida de Foco de un jTextField

Tags: java

Necesito hacer un convertidor de pulgadas a centímetros y viceversa. La idea es tener un solo botón "convertir" y que según el campo que acaba de perder Focus, me aparezca la conversión en el otro `JtextField` el resultado.

Ejemplo: Escribí en el campo centímetros un valor, y me tiene que aparecer en el campo pulgadas, y lo mismo si procedo al revés.

El problema es que no lo puedo hacer andar preguntando en el `action performed` del `Jbutton` la condición `if(CampoPulgadas.isFocusOwner)`.

Agradeceria la ayuda.

```
private void ConvertirBotonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

    double convertido = 0;

    if(!CampoCentimetros.isFocusOwner())
    {
        String cen = CampoCentimetros.getText();

        try{
            convertido = Double.parseDouble(cen);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "El valor "+convertido+" no es válido!", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

        convertido /= 2.54;

        cen = String.format("%.4f",convertido);

        CampoPulgadas.setText(cen);

        return;
    }
    if(CampoPulgadas.isFocusOwner())
    {
    } else {
        String pulg = CampoPulgadas.getText();

        try{
            convertido = Double.parseDouble(pulg);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "El valor "+convertido+" no es válido!", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

        convertido *= 2.54;

        pulg = String.format("%.4f", convertido);

        CampoCentimetros.setText(pulg);

        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si el componente tiene el foco, entonces al invocar el método `isFocusOwner` sobre esa instancia (el componente), devolverá `true`. Cuando haces clic sobre el botón "Convertir", éste es el dueño del foco, a menos que no sea *focusable*. <sup>**1**</sup>

De ahí que una posible solución es hacer que `ConvertirBoton` sea no *focusable*. Es decir:

```
ConvertirBoton.setFocusable(false);
```

Así, justo después de escribir o hacer algo en alguno de los campos de texto y hacer clic con el ratón, el campo de texto no perderá el foco. <sup>**2**</sup>

<sub>──────────────

1. Véanse más detalles de esto en [*How to Use the Focus Subsystem*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html).

2. El único inconveniente con esta solución es que no se podrá utilizar el teclado para pulsar el botón, sólo con el ratón.</sub>

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me anduvo de lujo!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes añadir un `FocusListener` a los campos de forma que cuando pierdan el foco conviertan la cantidad.

Incluso te recomendaría usar un `KeyListener` así la cantidad se iría convirtiendo a medida que se fuera escribiendo.